# Best way to edit certain system files without sudo

Tags: unix

On a Unix system, what is the best practice for editing system files such as `/etc/hosts` and `php.ini` as non-root without doing the tedious sudo+password?

Can I simply `chown` those files to my non-root-user, or is there a better way using groups or something?

Comment: I am not sure why you'd want to, those aren't files people typically edit frequently enough to need to bypass the protections that are in place for a reason. And no, don't change the ownership...

Answer (score 5):

`sudo` is the best and proper way to do it. If you give your user account too many administrative privileges (for example, adding yourself to the `root` group), you open yourself up to accidentally doing all sorts of harmful things. Also, malware/trojans could use your privileges without your knowledge to do nasty things. Just think of typing `sudo` before a command as an extra check - "Do I really want to run this?"

You can set up `sudo` (it should already be this way) to wait a specified length of time before asking for your password again, so if you're doing a bunch of admin tasks all at once you don't need to keep entering it.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to MattDMo's answer.  If retyping your password is bothering you, you can add `NOPASSWD` to your privileges. This will still require you to `sudo` (so you can be aware that you are doing something that could be harmful), but won't bother you for typing your password.

In `/etc/sudoers`, you can use this line:

`forthrin ALL=(ALL)   NOPASSWD: ALL`

Comment: This basically makes your user account like root's account and gives you far more privileges than just the ability to edit that specific file.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to open a new terminal and switch to root. Depending on how your system is set up you will be able to do this using one or more of the following ways:

- `sudo su`
- `sudo -i`
- `su`

Once you are the `root` user, simply keep thyat terminal open and edit any files you want from that terminal using `emacs` or `vim` or `gedit` or whatever you prefer:

```
emacs /etc/hosts
```

Comment: Or even `sudo -s`.

Answer (score 1):

`sudo` is what you want. As specified before, you can set custom timeouts before asking for a password again or specify `NOPASSWD:`
This can also be set for only a specific usergroup and command like this:

```
%usergroup ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /bin/vi
```

You could limit this command to a certain file by pointing to a script that runs `vi /etc/hosts`, but this would allow users to open other files as well from inside `vi` or drop into a shell from `vi` (`:!sh` or a similar command).

Comment: +1 for pointing out that once you allow `sudo vi` you've basically given user root access.